# Как посчитать значения повторяющихся значений в двух столбцах Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как посчитать значения для уникальных команд? В столбце Команда_1 есть повторяющиеся значения, которым соответствует столбец Результат_1, в Команда_2 есть также команды из столбца Команда_1 и им соответствует столбец Результат_2. Задача заключается в том, чтобы создать новый датафрейм (Команда, Очки): с уникальными командами из обоих столбцов, для которых подсчитаны очки (Результат_1 и Результат_2). Сложность в том, что одна команда может повторяться в одном столбце Команда_1 и также присутствовать в соседнем.Также для понимания: 3 очка дает победа, 1 ничья, проигрыш 0. Как написать эту функцию по подсчету?

[image: Датафрейм, к которому нужно написать функцию]

Вырезка из кода с подсчетами, на скрине результат ниже датафрейма:

````
    print(filtered_df)

    df1 = filtered_df.groupby('Команда_1',group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x)['Результат_1']# группирет по 'Команда_1' создающий ключи, оставляет результаты

    pobed_func_dom = lambda x: df1[x].value_counts()['3'] if '3' in df1[x].unique() else 0 #функция по Ключу обращается к команде и выдаёт количество выигрышей
    nich_func_dom = lambda x: df1[x].value_counts()['0'] if '0' in df1[x].unique() else 0 #функция по Ключу обращается к команде и выдаёт количество ничьих

    pobed_home = pd.Series(main_df1.apply(pobed_func_dom)) #создаёт датафрейм, где к каждому значению команды выполняется функция
    nich_home = pd.Series(main_df1.apply(nich_func_dom))

    home = pd.DataFrame({'Победа дома': pobed_home, 'Ничья дома':nich_home})
    home['О']=home['Победа дома'].mul(3).add(home['Ничья дома'])
    home.sort_values(['О'], ascending = False, inplace = True)
    home.set_index('О')

    df2 = filtered_df.groupby('Команда_2',group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x)['Результат_2']

    pobed_func_gost = lambda x: df2[x].value_counts()['В'] if 'В' in df2[x].unique() else 0
    nich_func_gost = lambda x: df2[x].value_counts()['Н'] if 'Н' in df2[x].unique() else 0

    pobed_gost = pd.Series(main_df2.apply(pobed_func_gost))
    nich_gost = pd.Series(main_df2.apply(nich_func_gost))

    away = pd.DataFrame({'Победа в гостях': pobed_gost, 'Ничья в гостях':nich_gost})
    away['О']=away['Победа в гостях'].mul(3).add(away['Ничья в гостях'])
    away.sort_values(['О'], ascending = False, inplace = True)
    away.set_index('О')
    print(home)
    print(away)```
````

Comment: не очень понял, что должно быть уникальным. Если вам надо посчитать так, чтобы у вас не было в наборе повторяющихся строк?